# KDE - Kmail: How to put message preview window on the right?

Tags: kde, kmail

Kmail shows message preview window below the messages thread. It there a way to put it on the right, like outlook does?

I.e. I would like to have three columns in KMail - folders, messages thread, preview window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In KDE 4.11 (but should work for previous versions too) Go to:

settings ->

configure ->

Appearance ->

layout ->

check "show message preview panel next to the message list"

Comment: Wonderful! Many thanks! Its the same in KDE 4.10 BTW.

Comment: Also works for KDE 5.8.8  KMail 5.2.3

Answer (score -1):

[image]

For visual reference. Kmail version 5.23.3